# Probability that a random walk reaches an arbitrary value in a given number of steps

Tags: probability, markov-chains, random-walk

I have a simple random walk over $\mathbb{Z}$:

$X_{i+1} = X_i - 1$ (probability $p$) or $X_i + 1$ (probability $1-p$)
and $X_0=0$

I want to find the probability of reaching an arbitrary negative value $-k$ in $n$ steps or less

I am not sure how to approach the problem, given that most of the examples I find are about the probability of reaching $-k$ in any number of steps (eg cliff-falling problems)

If I call $P(k,n)$ the probability of reaching $-k$ in $n$ steps or less, I think the following recursion holds (**edit: it does not!**):

$P(k+1,n+1)=P(k+1,n) + (1-P(k+1,n)) \times P(k,n) \times p$
with $P(k,k)=p^k \;\forall k>=0$
and $P(0,n)=1 \;\forall n>=0$

But I am not sure how to solve this, and not sure this is the right approach. Any help (with the recursion or with finding another approach) would be appreciated.

Comment: You have $(1-P(k+1,n)) \times P(k,n)$ as the probability of being at $-k$ after exactly $n$ steps, not having reached $-k-1$ in the meantime. But I don't think this is right. Firstly, the two events $P(k+1,n)$ and $P(k,n)$ are not independent; and secondly, $P(k,n)$ is the probability of having reached $-k$ in $n$ steps or less, not the probability of being at $-k$ at time $n$. But maybe I am missing something, and these two objections cancel each other out.

Comment: @TonyK: you are right, now I can see that my recursion is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by determining the probability of reaching -k in *exactly* n steps.

Consider an Example: $-k = -10$. As $X_i$ is odd iff $i$ is odd, the probability is zero if n is odd or $n<10$. Now assume for instance $n=20$. In order to reach $-10$, we have to walk to the left $15$ times ($-1$ case) and $5$ times to the right ($+1$ case).

As the order of these steps is **not** irrelevant, we obtain that the probability in this case is **smaller** than
\begin{align}
\binom{20}{5}p^{15}(1-p)^{5}.
\end{align}

Edit: The comment is, of course, correct - we have to avoid reaching $-10$ too early. So we have to figure out how many walks are "forbidden"...

Comment: I don't believe that this is correct, for reaching $-2$ in $8$ steps doesn't preclude having reached it in two steps; when you take the sum, you're double-counting for that two-step reach. But perhaps I'm misunderstanding. (BTW, this was exactly the same approach I 'wrote down' in my head in preparation for answering the question, and then abandoned!)

Comment: Urgh :( thank you! I hope my follow-up idea solves the problem.

Comment: That looks much better, and should be suitable for OP to generalize. Nice! (I wish I'd come up with that second half rather than abandoning the attempt and thinking "That must be in Feller somewhere...")

Comment: "a walk is "allowed" iff the five steps to the right are in the first 14 steps": how do you get this result?
What about the following walk: LLLLLLLLLRLRLRLRLRLL, which reaches -10 in 20 steps exactly, but does not satisfy your condition?

Comment: You're right. I forgot that LLLLLLLLLR allows L in the next step. This makes the counting harder ...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions!

Indeed I can write the probability of reaching -k in exactly n steps: it is $P(X_n = -k) \times \frac{k}{n} $ according to theorem 0.7 of http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~breed/MATH671/lecture2corrected.pdf

And thus I can sum to find the probability $p_{final}$ of reaching -k in n or less steps: $\sum_{i=k,k+2,...n} P(X_i = -k) \times \frac{k}{i}$

Since we know that $P(X_n = -k) = {n \choose \frac{n+k}{2}} \times p^\frac{n+k}{2} \times (1-p)^\frac{n-k}{2}$,
I get $p_{final} = \sum_{j=0,2,...n-k} {k+j \choose \frac{j}{2}} \times (p(1-p))^\frac{j}{2} \times \frac{k}{j+k} \times p^k$ after simplification.

I do not know how to simplify further, if possible?